# creating variable names from parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to create variable names from parameters passed to a function in javascript. Something like this:

```
function createVar(number) {
var "number" + number;
}
createVar(1)
```

I'm new to Stack Overflow and programming, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes it is.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @minseong ohaidere.  I think it's possible, but it's probably better to use an array

Comment: Why would this be useful anyway?

Comment: `eval('var prefix_' + number + ' = 100');`. But I don't want want to post this stupid code as answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to interpret Object as associative array where you specify index and get value by name of index ( hash ):

```
var x = Array();
x[number] = value;
```

Single variable name is for programmer, and the code would be hard to maintain and understand when you set variable dynamically in code.

Comment: Note that there are no "associative arrays" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't see why this would ever be useful, because every time you want to use the variable you'd have to search for it with your number argument.

However, you can do it, albeit not the exact way you had described:

```
function createVar(number){
  eval("var number" + number.toString() + ";");
}
```

however, this variable will only be accessible within the function, to make it global assign to the window object:

```
function createVar(number){
  window["number" + number] = 15; // creates "global" variable
}
```

As I've stated before, however, I don't see this being useful, [i]ever[/i], if you want to stratify values by numbers you'd be much better off with an array.

Comment: The "global variable" case can  be solved better with `window['number' + number] = 15;`.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, I see - does that avoid the eval?

Comment: In that case yes. Doesn't work for local variables of course. `eval` would be the only way for local variables, which is definitely the wrong thing to do anyway, that's why I said it's not possible ;) Knowing the actual problem the OP is trying to solve would allow us to provide an actual solution.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I agree. I'll quickly hop in and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach this to the `window` object, but note it will be global. For example:

```
function createVar(varName, value) {
    window[varName] = value;
}

createVar("test", "Hello World");
alert(test); // Outputs "Hello World".
```

Comment: Why not assign it to an Object?

Comment: @cyan Simplicity, because the OP probably want's the access the variable by just it's name. For example `test` other than `myObj.test` or `myObj["test"]`.